# How to get the memory base of .rdata?

Tags: debugging, assembly, memory, x86, ida

I am new to assembly language and try to get the memory base of the .rdata section because I would like to compare a string from there with a current string that's on the stack. I am using x64dbg.

Example: At a specific call I see the (relative) memory address from some data that is stored in .rdata, let's say it is `0x001C0000` and .rdata starts at `0x001A0000` and ends at `0x001F0000`. In x64dbg I can get the .rdata memory base by typing  `mem.base(0x001C0000)` which returns `0x001A0000` but how can I do it in x86 assembly language? What I am trying to do is access data from .rdata but I don't know the offset from the memory base. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you writing assembly code? In that case just use a label and let the linker take care of the address.

Comment: No I am disassembling a binary file actually. All I would like to know is the base of .rdata

Comment: I don't quite understand what you expect to do with the start address of `.rdata` (are you sure you don't mean `rodata`?).  If you want to compare a string in `.rdata` with a string on the stack, surely you only need the addresses of the two strings.

Comment: @Woods If it's an ELF binary, type `objdump -h binary.file` where `binary.file` is your binary.  This gives you the addresses off all sections in `binary.file` if section headers are included.

Comment: @fuz: `.rdata` is the Windows equivalent of Linux / OS X`.rodata`, or so I'm told.

Answer (score 0):

Use "dumpbin.exe". Here is how: suppose your file is "foo.exe",  do:

dumpbin.exe /all foo.exe >foo.txt

Then, open foo.txt and look for "SECTION HEADER #1" and check the name (for example ".text").  Then, look for "SECTION HEADER #2",   #3,  etc..

One of these will be named ".rdata".  Just under the name, you have the field "virtual address". That's what you want.